# Figured out the basic I want to do. But need to add PWM

Tags: c, mplab, pwm, xc8

Has a newbie to Code. I wanted to create the iconic TV Knight Rider scan. I have wrote my first code and achieved the basic function. I know there are many (already) made code for this and I have looked at various samples to get an idea of what I want to do. I added an all-on sequence in the beginning and figured out GOTO in code. Simple for most of you, but a building block for me :) Here is the working code for my 16F88 using MPLAB X IDE 5.45 and XC8

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "16F88_xc8_header.h"               // 16F88 CONFIG BITS

    #define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000                  // 4 MHz clock

    int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    __CONFIG(FOSC_INTRCCLK&WDTE_OFF&MCLRE_OFF); 
    
        OSCCONbits.IRCF = 0b110;        // Binary value of the three ICRF bits to select 4 MHz internal oscillator
            
        TRISB = 0x00;
        PORTB = 0x00;
        
        { 
        PORTB = 0b00111111;             // ALL-ON EFFECT
        __delay_ms(400);
        PORTB = 0b00011111;
        __delay_ms(80);
        PORTB = 0b00001111;
        __delay_ms(80);
        PORTB = 0b00000111;
        __delay_ms(80);
        PORTB = 0b00000011;
        __delay_ms(80);
         }
     
        
        {
        kitt_scan:
        PORTB = 0b00000001;            // 6LED SCAN STARTS
        __delay_ms(400);
        PORTB = 0b00000010;
        __delay_ms(400);
        PORTB = 0b00000100;
        __delay_ms(400);
        PORTB = 0b00001000;
        __delay_ms(400);
        PORTB = 0b00010000;
        __delay_ms(400);
        PORTB = 0b00100000;
        __delay_ms(400);
        PORTB = 0b00010000;
        __delay_ms(400);
        PORTB = 0b00001000;
        __delay_ms(400);
        PORTB = 0b00000100;
        __delay_ms(400);
        PORTB = 0b00000010;
        __delay_ms(400);
        
        goto kitt_scan;
        
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
  
}
```

The next thing I want to add is PWM to give the LEDs a trailing effect when the light pattern moves side to side. I have googled of course, but what I found is how to make one LED fade low to high. This is not what I want, instead I would like to have option to have a pre-determined output value that I can assign in the code.

For instance,

```
0=LED OFF
1=LED at 30% Duty Cycle (very DIM LED)
2=LED at 70% Duty Cycle (somewhat DIM LED)
3=LED at 100% Duty Cycle (full bright LED)
```

That way I hope to code it like this:

```
 PORTB = 0b00000003;           
    __delay_ms(400);
    PORTB = 0b00000032;
    __delay_ms(400);
    PORTB = 0b00000321;
    __delay_ms(400);
```

So my question is, where do I start to even accomplish this? Any and all insight is welcome.

Thank you
TONY

Comment: Better to pick one language.

Comment: I do not believe there's C++ on xc8 on 16F88.

Comment: This:    `__CONFIG(FOSC_INTRCCLK&WDTE_OFF&MCLRE_OFF); ` is not an instruction and should not be placed in the main loop.

Answer (score 1):

**For electronics**

I'd just put a capacitor in parallel with each LED, so that when an LED is turned on it also charges the capacitor, and when the LED is turned "off" the LED fades while the capacitor discharges. :-)

**For plain C (or C++)**

*WARNING: I tested none of this so there's probably bugs in my example code. Learning to fix bugs is as important as learning to create bugs, so if there are bugs you'll learn more!*

Assume you have a counter that starts at zero and is incremented every 1 ms; and when it reaches 4 you reset the counter to zero; like this:

```
    int counter = 0;
    
nextTick:
    __delay_ms(1);
    counter++;
    if(counter >= 4) {
        counter = 0;
    }

    goto nextTick;
```

If you turn an LED on when the counter is zero and turn the LED off when the counter is 1, then the LED will be on for 25% of the time and off for 75% of the time. This might look like:

```
    int counter = 0;
    
    PORTB = 0b00000001;

nextTick:
    __delay_ms(1);
    counter++;
    if(counter >= 4) {
        counter = 0;
        PORTB = 0b00000001;
    }

    if(counter == 1) {
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
    }

    goto nextTick;
```

If you turn the LED off when the counter is 2 then the LED will be on for 50% of the time; if you turn the LED off when the counter is 3 then the LED will be on for 75% of the time; if you turn the LED off when the counter is greater than or equal to 4 (which never happens because its reset to zero first) the LED will be on for 100% of the time; and if you turn the LED off when the counter is zero then the LED will be on for "almost 0%" of the time.

You can use a variable to control "how much the LED should be on", like:

```
    int counter = 0;
    int LED0_timeOn = 2;
    
    PORTB = 0b00000001;

nextTick:
    __delay_ms(1);
    counter++;
    if(counter >= 4) {
        counter = 0;
        PORTB = 0b00000001;
    }

    if(counter == LED0_timeOn) {
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
    }

    goto nextTick;
```

This is slightly clumsy, because when the LED is supposed to be on for 0% of the time you'd turn it on and then turn it off again. You can avoid that by using a variable and only setting PORTB once per tick, like this:

```
    int counter = 0;
    int nextPortBvalue = 0b00000001;
    int LED0_timeOn = 2;
    

nextTick:
    PORTB = nextPortBvalue;
    __delay_ms(1);
    counter++;
    if(counter >= 4) {
        counter = 0;
        nextPortBvalue = 0b00000001;
    }

    if(counter == LED0_timeOn) {
        nextPortBvalue = 0b00000000;
    }

    goto nextTick;
```

If you had 6 variables you could have 6 LEDs each with a different "time spent on"; like:

```
    int counter = 0;
    int nextPortBvalue = 0b00111111;
    int LED0_timeOn = 0;
    int LED1_timeOn = 1;
    int LED2_timeOn = 2;
    int LED3_timeOn = 3;
    int LED4_timeOn = 4;
    int LED5_timeOn = 0;
    
nextTick:
    PORTB = nextPortBvalue;
    __delay_ms(1);
    counter++;
    if(counter >= 4) {
        counter = 0;
        nextPortBvalue = 0b00111111;
    }

    if(counter == LED0_timeOn) {
        nextPortBvalue &= ~0b00000001;
    }
    if(counter == LED1_timeOn) {
        nextPortBvalue &= ~0b00000010;
    }
    if(counter == LED2_timeOn) {
        nextPortBvalue &= ~0b00000100;
    }
    if(counter == LED3_timeOn) {
        nextPortBvalue &= ~0b00001000;
    }
    if(counter == LED4_timeOn) {
        nextPortBvalue &= ~0b00010000;
    }
    if(counter == LED5_timeOn) {
        nextPortBvalue &= ~0b00100000;
    }

    goto nextTick;
```

This is a little tricky - to turn one bit (or one LED) off without messing up the other bits it needs to use AND to turn off everything except one bit. The `~0b00000010` means "invert these bits", so `~0b00000010` becomes `0b11111101`, and `nextPortBvalue &= ~0b00000010;` means "the new value of `nextPortBvalue` is the same as the old value AND 0b11111101" (causing the second bit to be turned off while leaving all the other bits the same).

This is a little messy though - it's duplicating logic 6 times (once for each LED). You can fix that by using an array and a loop, like:

```
    int counter = 0;
    int nextPortBvalue = 0b00111111;
    int LED_timeOn[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 };
    
nextTick:
    PORTB = nextPortBvalue;
    __delay_ms(1);
    counter++;
    if(counter >= 4) {
        counter = 0;
        nextPortBvalue = 0b00111111;
    }
    for(int bit = 0; bit < 6; bit++) {
        if(counter == LED_timeOn[bit]) {
            nextPortBvalue &= ~(0b00000001 << bit);
        }
    }

    goto nextTick;
```

Now that you can control how much time each LED spends on (or off); you'll want something that changes the values in the `LED_timeOn` array (and changes  how long each LED spends on). You were doing this every 400 ms, so let's add a second counter to measure 400 ms:

```
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int nextPortBvalue = 0b00111111;
    int LED_timeOn[6] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0 };
    
nextTick:
    PORTB = nextPortBvalue;
    __delay_ms(1);
    counter1++;
    counter2++;
    if(counter1 >= 4) {
        counter1 = 0;
        nextPortBvalue = 0b00111111;
    }
    if(counter2 >= 400) {
        counter2 = 0;
    }

    for(int bit = 0; bit < 6; bit++) {
        if(counter1 == LED_timeOn[bit]) {
            nextPortBvalue &= ~(0b00000001 << bit);
        }
    }

    goto nextTick;
```

Every 400 ms you want all the existing "time LEDs spend on" to be decreased (so the LEDs fade), and then set a new "100% on" LED. You'll want another variable to keep track of which LED is the next "100% on" LED. It ends up like this:

```
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int nextPortBvalue = 0b00111111;
    int LED_timeOn[6] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int nextOnLED = 0;
    
nextTick:
    PORTB = nextPortBvalue;
    __delay_ms(1);
    counter1++;
    counter2++;
    if(counter1 >= 4) {
        counter1 = 0;
        nextPortBvalue = 0b00111111;
    }
    if(counter2 >= 400) {
        counter2 = 0;
        /* Make all the LEDs fade */
        for(int bit = 0; bit < 6; bit++) {
            if(LED_timeOn[bit] > 0) {
                LED_timeOn[bit]--;
            }
        }
        /* Change the value for the next "100% on" LED to 4 */
        LED_timeOn[nextOnLED] = 4;
    }

    for(int bit = 0; bit < 6; bit++) {
        if(counter1 == LED_timeOn[bit]) {
            nextPortBvalue &= ~(0b00000001 << bit);
        }
    }

    goto nextTick;
```

The final problem is that you also want to change which LED is the next "100% on" LED; but sometimes it's the next LED to the left, and sometimes it's the next LED to the right. One way to handle that would be to pretend that there's 4 fake LEDs in the middle; so that after the 6th LED was turned on you'd turn on the 7th "fake LED" (which is actually the 5th LED again!). Here's what that might look like:

```
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int nextPortBvalue = 0b00111111;
    int LED_timeOn[6] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int nextOnLED = 0;
    
nextTick:
    PORTB = nextPortBvalue;
    __delay_ms(1);
    counter1++;
    counter2++;
    if(counter1 >= 4) {
        counter1 = 0;
        nextPortBvalue = 0b00111111;
    }
    if(counter2 >= 400) {
        counter2 = 0;
        /* Make all the LEDs fade */
        for(int bit = 0; bit < 6; bit++) {
            if(LED_timeOn[bit] > 0) {
                LED_timeOn[bit]--;
            }
        }
        /* Change the value for the next "100% on" LED to 4 */
        if(nextOnLED < 6) {
            LED_timeOn[nextOnLED] = 4;       /* A real LED */
        } else {
            LED_timeOn[10 - nextOnLED] = 4;  /* A fake LED */
        }
        /* Update the next 100% on LED */
        nextOnLED++;
        if(nextOnLED >= 10) {
            nextOnLED = 0;
        }
    }

    for(int bit = 0; bit < 6; bit++) {
        if(counter1 == LED_timeOn[bit]) {
            nextPortBvalue &= ~(0b00000001 << bit);
        }
    }

    goto nextTick;
```